# Is there a built-in pyspark function for the paradigm union(filter, take)?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Essentially, filtering by key, taking a specific number (based on key) from the DataFrame, and unioning these results for a number of values.

For example,

`| First Name    | Last Name     |
|------------   |-----------    |
| Jim           | Pratchett     |
| Jim           | Adams         |
| Karen         | Gaiman        |
| Karen         | Bryson        |
| Karen         | Amis          |
| Steve         | Wodehouse     |
| Steve         | Hiassen       |
| Steve         | Heller        |
| Steve         | Toole         |
| Steve         | Sedaris       |`

Let's say my filtering dictionary is as follows -

`{
    'Jim': 1,
    'Karen': 2,
    'Steve': 3,
}`

So I want 1 Jim, 2 Karens and 3 Steves from my DataFrame. I'm not frightfully picky about which ones I end up with. I figured that the standard way to do it would be to filter and take for each key, value pair, and then union all the DataFrames.

I was wondering if there is a) a better way to approach this problem or b) a built in function to address the union(filter, take) paradigm I mentioned earlier.